# Adding Scatter Dots to Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart.js

Tags: javascript, html, angular, chart.js

I have the following horizontal stacked bar chart.[image: chart image]

However, I am trying to add pink scatter dots onto the chart (based on the right y axis numbers), but they aren't showing up. Can anyone advise what I am doing wrong please?

It seems if i change the chart to normal bar, and not horizontal, the dots show up, however I need it to be horizontal.

Here is my component.ts code:

```
  public disproportionChartData = [
    {
      label: "Disproportionality",
      data: [100, 40, 0, -40, -90],
      type: "scatter",
      fill: false,
    },
    {
      label: "Population 1 %",
      data: [-10, -40, -80, -70, -20],
    },
    {
      label: "Population 2 %",
      data: [10, 20, 30, 50, 90],
    },
  ];
  public disproportionChartLabels = [
    "Type 1",
    "Type 2",
    "Type 3",
    "Type 4",
    "Type 5",
  ];
  public disproportionChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: "top",
    },
    title: {
      display: false,
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          position: "top",
          stacked: true,
          ticks: {
            callback(value) {
              return Math.abs(value);
            },
            min: -100,
            max: 100,
          },
        },
      ],

      yAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true,
          position: "left",
          ticks: {
            callback: function (value, index, values) {
              return value < 0 ? -value : value;
            },
          },
        },
        {
          stacked: true,
          position: "right",
          ticks: {
            callback(value) {
              return value;
            },
            min: -100,
            max: 100,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };
```

Here is my html code:

```
<canvas
  baseChart
  [datasets]="disproportionChartData"
  [labels]="disproportionChartLabels"
  [options]="disproportionChartOptions"
  [chartType]="'horizontalBar'"
>
</canvas>
```

UPDATE

Got this working thanks to user2057925, however, does anyone know how I can add a label to the tooltip (to match the types)
[image]

For example, the title of the tooltip should be 'Type 4', instead of -90. There will be a pink dot for every type on the left y axis. Or, remove the tooltip completely and just have a title next to each dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could specify the `id` and the `type` of the axes used by scatter chart. Furthermore use `xAxisID` and `yAxisID` to related teh scatter dataset to those axes. AFAIK scatter needs data points in order to show the points.

EDIT: added tooltip callback to show always the label.

EDIT 2: added DataLabels plugin https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels to show the label on the right of the pink point.

```js
const disproportionChartData = [
    {
      label: "Disproportionality",
      data: [{y: 80, x:80}, {x:40, y:40}, {y:0, x:0}, {y:-40, x:-40}, {y:-80, x:-80}],
      borderColor: 'pink',
      backgroundColor: 'pink',
      pointRadius: 10,
      type: "scatter",
      xAxisID: 'x2',
      yAxisID: 'y2',
      datalabels: {
        display: true,
        align: 'right',
        color: 'black',
        formatter: function(value, context) {
          return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
        }
      }
    },
    {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      label: "Population 1 %",
      data: [-10, -40, -80, -70, -20],
    },
    {
      type: 'horizontalBar',
      label: "Population 2 %",
      data: [10, 20, 30, 50, 90],
    },
  ];
  const disproportionChartLabels = [
    "Type 1",
    "Type 2",
    "Type 3",
    "Type 4",
    "Type 5",
  ];
  const disproportionChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: "top",
    },
    title: {
      display: false,
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        title (items) {
          const ds2 = items.filter(element => element.datasetIndex === 1);
          return ds2[0].label;
        }
      }
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        display: false
      }
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          id: 'x2',
          type: 'linear',
          position: "top",
          ticks: {
            callback(value) {
              return Math.abs(value);
            },
            min: -100,
            max: 100,
          },
        },
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true,
          position: "left",
          ticks: {
            callback: function (value, index, values) {
              return value < 0 ? -value : value;
            },
          },
        },
        {
          id: 'y2',
          stacked: true,
          position: "right",
          ticks: {
            callback(value) {
              return value;
            },
            min: -100,
            max: 100,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
Chart.plugins.register(ChartDataLabels);
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: {
        labels: disproportionChartLabels,
        datasets: disproportionChartData
    },
    options: disproportionChartOptions
});
```

```css
.myChartDiv {
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-plugin-datalabels@1.0.0/dist/chartjs-plugin-datalabels.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="myChartDiv">
      <canvas id="myChart" width="600" height="400"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this does work. However, how do I add a type label to the pink dots tooltip? There should be 5 pink dots, each one relating to a type on the left axis. Is this possible? I have updated my question to reflect this

Comment: I have changed the answer (the snippet) adding the tooltip callback in order to see the label and not the value

Comment: Thank you very much. I have marked your answer as correct so you get credit. Is there a way to display the label next to the pink dot without a tooltip?

Comment: If I have understood well, you would like to have the pink point and on its right (for instance) "Type 1", or other. Correct? If yes, I think the datalabels plugin could be the solution

Comment: Yes exactly that!

Comment: I don't suppose you have an example of that working? Just on the pink dots, not on the bar chart

Comment: yes, I have it. Have a look here: https://codepen.io/stockinail/pen/KKoLrKp

Comment: I have changed the answer accordingly

Comment: Is this possible to get it working using v1 of the datalabels plugin? As that is the only one compatible with my code

Comment: If you have a look to both snippet of the answer and codepen, I'm using datalabels version 1, last available for CHART.JS version 2 that I assumed you are using. Therefore you can use version 1

Comment: Sorry, yes I hadn't added the correct plugin name to the html. Thank you