# Alternative to using "chartjs-plugin-datalabels" to add labels to scatter

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I am trying to add labels to the pink scatter dots (but not the green bars) on the following ngchart horizontal bar chart

[image: chart image]

However, if I try to use:

```
import ChartDataLabels from "chartjs-plugin-datalabels";
```

I get the following errors:

```
     Error: node_modules/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/types/context.d.ts:1:16 - error TS2724: Module '"../../@types/chart.js"' has no exported member 'ChartDataset'. Did you mean 'ChartDataSets'?

1 import {Chart, ChartDataset} from 'chart.js';
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~
node_modules/chartjs-plugin-datalabels/types/index.d.ts:1:20 - error TS2305: Module '"../../@types/chart.js"' has no exported member 'Plugin'.

1 import {ChartType, Plugin} from 'chart.js';
                     ~~~~~~
```

Does anyone know an alternative library I could use to add labels to my pink scatter dots, or a way to fix these errors?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

Thanks to @LeeLenalee I have now installed v1 of the library, however it isn't showing any labels next to the dots. Can anyone tell why? Here is my code for the chart:

```
  public disproportionChartData = [
    {
      label: "Disproportionality",
      data: [
        { y: 80, x: 80 },
        { x: 40, y: 40 },
        { y: 0, x: 0 },
        { y: -40, x: -40 },
        { y: -80, x: -80 },
      ],
      borderColor: "pink",
      backgroundColor: "pink",
      pointRadius: 10,
      type: "scatter",
      xAxisID: "x2",
      yAxisID: "y2",
      datalabels: {
        display: true,
        align: "right",
        color: "black",
        formatter: function (value, context) {
          return context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
        },
      },
    },
    {
      type: "horizontalBar",
      label: "Population 1 %",
      data: [-10, -40, -80, -70, -20],
    },
    {
      type: "horizontalBar",
      label: "Population 2 %",
      data: [10, 20, 30, 50, 90],
    },
  ];
  public disproportionChartLabels = [
    "Type 1",
    "Type 2",
    "Type 3",
    "Type 4",
    "Type 5",
  ];
  public disproportionChartPlugins = [ChartDataLabels];
  public disproportionChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      position: "top",
    },
    title: {
      display: false,
    },
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        title(items) {
          const ds2 = items.filter((element) => element.datasetIndex === 1);
          return ds2[0].label;
        },
      },
    },
    plugins: {
      datalabels: {
        display: false,
      },
    },
    scales: {
      xAxes: [
        {
          id: "x2",
          type: "linear",
          position: "top",
          ticks: {
            callback(value) {
              return Math.abs(value);
            },
            min: -100,
            max: 100,
          },
        },
      ],
      yAxes: [
        {
          stacked: true,
          position: "left",
          ticks: {
            callback: function (value, index, values) {
              return value < 0 ? -value : value;
            },
          },
        },
        {
          id: "y2",
          stacked: true,
          position: "right",
          ticks: {
            callback(value) {
              return value;
            },
            min: -100,
            max: 100,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using V2 of the datalabels plugin with V2 of chart.js this does not work since it is for chart.js v3, you need to use V1 of the datalabels plugin to work with your version of chart.js

Comment: Thank you, i have downgraded to v1, which removes the errors, but the labels still aren't showing on the chart. Have updated my question. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to import and register the plugin: https://v1_0_0--chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#integration

Answer (score 0):

As reported in the question [Adding Scatter Dots to Horizontal Stacked Bar Chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73502909/adding-scatter-dots-to-horizontal-stacked-bar-chart-js/73528368), you must use Datalabels version 1.
Both provided snippet and codepen are using Datalabels version 1.
I think you don't register the plugin (see snippet code in the other question).

```
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
Chart.plugins.register(ChartDataLabels); // --> I think this is missing
const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
```